# removing duplication in xml

Tags: html, xml

In any sort of XML document (and I'm talking mostly HTML here), you get things like this:

```
<element attr="val"> content </element>
```

Or, worse:

```
<element attr="val"></element> <!-- yes, <element /> is good, too, but not 
                                    all browsers support this for all tags -->
```

Are there any macro "languages" that remove this duplication, allowing you to do things like:

```
<element attr="val">{ content }
```

or something, and then run a parser to generate:

```
<element>content</element>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/), It looks like what you need.